# what index values are allowed for array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, d3.js, ecmascript-6

Today I was exploring the [d3-time](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) library, with the help of the library we can create date-axis.
i have come across this [line](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/src/time.js#L83) in one of the file . could any one please explain how dose this line works in javascript.

```js
i = tickIntervals[target / tickIntervals[i - 1][2] < tickIntervals[i][2] / target ? i - 1 : i];
```

screen shot for the same
[image]

and below is the screen shot for the all the variables which are appearing in the above line. I have debugged and collected all the values at that time of execution of this line

[image]

can anybody please explain me what will be index result. it is actually taking `12`
here I want to understand that how it got value `12`.

I mean after executing the above line with present data the `i=tickIntervals[12]`

If this is not the right platform to ask this question please guide where to put this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading this code out loud I would say:

On this line, we're trying to find the suitable tick size for the target duration, in tickIntervals, an array of possible intervals (second, minute, hour…).

The bisection above has identified two durations, one below the target (i-1, with duration0 = `tickIntervals[i-1][2]`), the other above it (i, with duration1). We now need to find which is closest to our target.

The durations in tickIntervals are of increasing magnitude. As such, the comparison can't be done linearly (15 minutes is 15 times a minute and 1/4 times an hour, so it's closer to using hour ticks than using minutes ticks).

Instead of using a logarithm to measure the difference, this line compares target / duration0 with duration1 / target, which gives an equivalent result, but is faster to compute. This explains `target / tickIntervals[i - 1][2] < tickIntervals[i][2] / target`.

If this comparison is true, then we use the lower interval (`tickIntervals[i - 1]`), else the upper (`tickIntervals[i]`).

The `?:` operators have lowest precedence, so it's evaluated as

```
(target / tickIntervals[i - 1][2] < tickIntervals[i][2] / target) ? i - 1 : i
```

I hope this reading is correct and clarifies the intent.

Comment: @fill i have understood the code, but not the javascript. the below 
[target / tickIntervals[i - 1][2] < tickIntervals[i][2] / target ? i - 1 : i]  it will get converted to like this --> [86400000 / 86400000< 172800000 / 12  ]

how did this become to [12]..

Comment: i just want to understand the javascript.. how is it index value [12]

Comment: Operator precedence makes

(target / tickIntervals[i - 1][2] < tickIntervals[i][2] / target) ? i -1 : 1